# jQuery Selector - <i class>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to inject jQuery into a HTML page to create a popup window when I click a link on the page. I'm having trouble with the Selector and/or Syntax.

HTML

```
<a href="/leads/19365876/edit" class="hoverable edit">
 <i class="icon-pencil">
 </i>
</a>
```

Attempted Solution

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('a.hoverable.edit').live('click', function(){
        newwindow=window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Aside from the fact that `.live` is ancient. What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` Seriously? When you can just do `this.href`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 they give different results (actual attribute text vs fully-qualified URL, not that it matters in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to give '_blank' name to your window:

```
window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_blank','height=200,width=150');
```